# How can i pass a parameter to controller from the Cronjob?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller like the following

```
public function get($value)
{
  echo $value;
}
```

I want to add pass a parameter from the cronjob to the previous function 
i used the following but not working with me, i don't know why

```
php /home/fgadvx/public_html/twitterapi/index.php/ welcome get "a"
```

I used the example in the codeigniiter documentation found [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/cli.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should add commandline parameters to a php file, just like you would for any command.
In this case, your command is basically the `php` command, with the `file` as parameter. This looks in essence like this.

```
php index.php
```

or, because you use a path, it is

```
php /home/fgadvx/public_html/twitterapi/index.php
```

now you want to add more parameters. Make sure that these are NOT added to the file you wish to execute, but like so:

```
php index.php something otherthing "combo thing"
```

Your example adds something to the end (a `/`) which makes the `php` command not-find your file: there is no file called index.php/. You should really be aware of the difference between asking a server for a file and executing a command on your machine.

so probably in your case you ware looking for:

```
php /home/fgadvx/public_html/twitterapi/index.php welcome get "a"
```

(command `php`, file `index.php`, first paramtere welcome, second parameter `get`, last parameter `a`)
I doubt you need the " around `a` btw, but this is a valid call. Now if your index.php can handle this is a second thing (I see no mention of `get` in your link, but this seems to be the equivalent of going to `index.php/welcome/get/a` ?)

Comment: and somehow the cronjob get the `index` function not the `get` function

Comment: well, this was the biggest problem, the way you called it. IF it doesn't work, it could be anything. Is the 'twitterapi' a codeigniter project? is your class 'welcome' extending `CI_Controller `, is it saved to the right place, etc?, would you normally call twitterapi/index.php/welcome/get/a ?, does your function have a paramter? etc